# expecting returned exception from mock object method

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Inside my test I'm having mock object which should test expected NotImplementedException thrown from MyService.Create method

I'm struggle in this part

```
var hotelServiceMock = new Mock<HotelService>();
    hotelServiceMock.Setup(x=>x.Create(It.IsAny<HotelToCreateDTO>(), true))
                    .Throws(() => NotImplementedException());
```

I was think to use Returns instead of thrown (seen somewhere on net for some expected value, not exception) but on intellisense I'm getting only
[image]

Comment: Is it not **hotelServiceMock.Setup(x=>x.Create(It.IsAny<HotelToCreateDTO>(), true)).Throws<NotImplementedException>()** ?

Comment: @RonBeyer good eye ron :) Thanks. Post I will accept as valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Moq (I should) but from the Intellisense it looks like it should be:

```
hotelServiceMock.Setup(x=>x.Create(It.IsAny<HotelToCreateDTO>(), true)).Throws<NotImplementedException>()
```